# Setting A System For Public Use

Tags: permissions, networking, users

I am setting a system up for public use

I want to set some rules on the usage of computer so that the users are restricted to some particular areas of the system and they don't play with sensitive options

1. The users will have ftp & Remote access to their desktop (just 2 services )
2. The users can run some basic commands only (For Example from command line they can only run "mkdir , rm -rf , & some basics commands )
3. The users will remain in their home directories & cannot go back up from their home directories ( for example user "one" can not cd /home , will remain in there home directory so user "one" cannot see other users in the home directory )
4. The users can only use specific application (For Example  user "one" can only use libre office ,firefox & some basic applications like calculator etc.)
5. The users will be restricted for network usage ( For Example user "one" can only use 100 kb for download and for upload 50 kb )

I am going to set it up on Ubuntu.

## UPDATE

How do i setup ? , the above 5 points i want to setup for users

Comment: Nice and quite interesting but... where is the question?

Comment: And your question is? Please change it into a question where we can help you or some moderator will close it faster than you have set this up ;) Oh and have a search for 'Ubuntu kiosk'.

Comment: my question is how do i do these 5 restriction

Comment: 2. The users can....what?

Comment: sorry now updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the exactly 1-5, but 1-4 you get for free with "Guest Session" in Ubuntu.

It might be a good starting point.

Here is a tutorial how to [customize the guest session](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566078).

Comment: its abt the guest session .... when user log off all files which user have created will be lost ....am i rite ?...i want users to have there save folders in there home directories

Comment: @OneZero: I din't try it, but files are stored in /var/guest-data and I think it can be configured. Also, /media/** has rw access, so you can create /media/MYDATA/ to store files there.