# About ubuntu Login System:

Tags: login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting A System For Public Use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92427/setting-a-system-for-public-use)

does anyone know if ubuntu can configure to login system in my workstation.I mean if someone login with their account they can only use specific application then automatically closed or return to login screen if times run out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92427/setting-a-system-for-public-use

Answer (score 0):

The  timeouts  file  is  used  by timeoutd(8) to carry out such kind of limitations on how long a user can be idle or how long a user's session can be valid in each day. You can customize according to your needs. But please have look at this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man5/timeouts.5.html).